# Inclusion of ragged2e causes spacing side-effect in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, memoir, ragged2e

I am working on a [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document whose chapter titles are styled with Tikz. My actual graphic is quite a bit more complex, but for the sake of simplicity, the MWEs in this question will simply consist of a diagonal red line (spanning the whole `\textwidth`) and the right-aligned chapter name.

In this document, I also have to use the [`ragged2e` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) (in order to achieve a hyphenated ragged-right alignment in a table). There mere action of *including* this package by means of `\usepackage`, however, seems to have the side-effect of changing the spacing in the Tikz graphic.

First, the MWE that works without any issues:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter~#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\sffamily\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,-.1) rectangle (\textwidth,1.1\baselineskip);

  \draw[solid, draw=red] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node[align=right, anchor=center, text width=\textwidth] (headline) at ($(0,0)!0.5!(\textwidth,\baselineskip)$) {\thechapter~\textbf{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter with spaces}

abc

\end{document}
```

When compiling this document, the chapter title looks like it should:

[image: correctly spaced chapter title]

Now, the only change to the MWE is to include `ragged2e`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter~#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\sffamily\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,-.1) rectangle (\textwidth,1.1\baselineskip);

  \draw[solid, draw=red] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node[align=right, anchor=center, text width=\textwidth] (headline) at ($(0,0)!0.5!(\textwidth,\baselineskip)$) {\thechapter~\textbf{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter with spaces}

abc

\end{document}
```

Compiling now produces the chapter title as follows:

[image: chapter title with oversized whitespace between each word]

Obviously, the whitespace between each word within the chapter name has suddenly grown considerably. Interestingly, the space between the chapter number and the first word of the chapter name does *not* grow, even if the `~` is replaced with a .

**How can I prevent this extra whitespace from happening?**

Please do not suggestions that involve changing the Tikz code. As noted above, in the actual document, it is quite a complex graphic that has been carefully layouted. **I simply want to use `ragged2e` without any side-effects by merely importing the package.**

Curiously, my *actual* problem in my *actual* document is a bit different: There, both chapter titles and page headings are styled with Tikz. Chapter titles turn out normal, but chapter names in *page headings* (i.e. `\leftmark`) end up with these oversized whitespaces as soon as `ragged2e` is included. I was unable to reproduce this issue for an MWE, and instead managed to produce an MWE that exhibits the equivalent problem in the chapter titles. As this problem seems to be very similar to that in my actual document, I *hope* solutions for this question will also help with the actual issue.

Comment: That is really strange. You can try this in the title node `\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft \thechapter~\textbf{#1}}` there is still a small difference with and without `ragged2e` but not as noticable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tikz` ways of changing font attributes inside a node, i.e., instead of `\textbf{#1}` use `font=\bfseries` in the options. This will make the number bold too. There you may use `\normalfont`.

```
\node[align=right,  text width=\textwidth,font=\bfseries] (headline) at ($(0,0)!0.5!(\textwidth,\baselineskip)$) {{\normalfont\thechapter}~#1};
```

`anchor=center` is superfluous so I removed it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter~#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\sffamily\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,-.1) rectangle (\textwidth,1.1\baselineskip);

  \draw[solid, draw=red] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node[align=right,  text width=\textwidth,font=\bfseries] (headline) at ($(0,0)!0.5!(\textwidth,\baselineskip)$) {{\normalfont\thechapter}~#1};

\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter with spaces}

abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fascinating, this seems to work. Mind to add a brief explanation of what is going on there behind the scenes (in case you know)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: It is some what more complex and low level. When you use `align=right` with `text width` and try to change the font attributes in the middle of the text, the `ragged2e` tries to implement TeX style raggedness where the left side is balanced to its best. So that spreading occurs. So don't try to change the attributes in the middle but well in advance as done by `font=\bfseries`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: There is another option in `tikz`: `align=flush right` which when used in your definition of node works well. Try `\node[align=flush right,text width=\textwidth] (headline) at ($(0,0)!0.5!(\textwidth,\baselineskip)$) {\thechapter~\textbf{#1}};` with `ragged2e` to see what I mean.

Comment: @HarishKumar: This still to me looks like a bug in ragged2e. :-(

Comment: I can report that this issue persists in 2021 and I agree with @MartinSchröder that this looks like a bug in ragged2e.

Comment: @RicoPicone Please file a bug with ragged2e at https://gitlab.com/TeXhackse/ragged2e/-/issues